# how to declare a matrix with its indexs in the bottom left = 0 0

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make a matrix full of zeros like this

```
2|0 0 0 0
1|0 0 0 0
0|0 0 0 0
 ---------
  0 1 2 3
```

the particular thing with this matrix is its indexes at bottom left are 0 0

I used two lists but this didnt help     `world=[[0 for x in range(6)] for y in range(4)]` this gave me

```
0|0 0 0 0
1|0 0 0 0
2|0 0 0 0
 ---------
  0 1 2 3
```

because i hade to convert so many times this makes code difficult to understand

I would like to know if there is another way of doing this usinig numpy

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, SO is not a free code-writing website, or a tutorial service.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve] showing how you've attempted to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you cannot really reverse the way indexes work (i.e. left-right and top-down). At least the way they work in terms of presentation.

For your use case you can just keep a regular matrix, with regular indexes, then whenever you want to present it - just do:

```py
import numpy as np

x=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(x)
print(x[::-1,:])
```

Output:

```py
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]

[[7 8 9]
 [4 5 6]
 [1 2 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create this with numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.zeros([3,4], dtype=int)                                                                                                                                                          

#array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```